# All possible paths algorithm

Tags: algorithm, mathematical-optimization, graph-algorithm

I'm not very comfortable with math algorithms, and would need to use one for a project I'm working on. I have found answers for point A to point B, but none that really match what I'm looking for. I am looking for the best time efficient algorithm to accomplish this task:

For an input :

```
Points {
    In
    Out
}

[Bridge]Points = {
    "AB-1" = {"A", "B"}
    "AB-2" = {"A", "B"}
    "BA-1" = {"B", "A"}
    "BA-2" = {"B", "A"}
    "AC-1" = {"A", "C"}
    "AC-2" = {"A", "C"}
    "CA-1" = {"C", "A"}
    "CA-2" = {"C", "A"}
    "BC-1" = {"B", "C"}
    "BC-2" = {"B", "C"}
    "CB-1" = {"C", "B"}
    "CB-2" = {"C", "B"}
}
```

Each "bridge" represent 2 "points" : First value is an "in" and the second in an "out".

Each path can use each unique bridge only once.
Different bridges can have the same in/out (like *"BC-1"*,*"BC-2"*, ..), and each unique bridge must have a different in and out (*"AA-1" = {"A", "A"}* is not possible).

The goal is to obtain EVERY POSSIBLE paths given a start point and an end point, which can be the same points (*A->A*, *B->B*, ..).

For A to A expected output :

```
AB-1 -> BA-1
AB-1 -> BA-2
AB-2 -> BA-1
AC-1 -> CA-2
AB-1 -> BA-1 -> AB-2 -> BA-2
AB-1 -> BA-2 -> AC-1 -> CB-2 -> BA-1
AC-2 -> CA-1 -> AB-1 -> BA-2
AC-1 -> CA-1 -> AB-2 -> BC-1 -> CA-2
...
```

Also, the possibility of defining a maximum path length (to avoid subsequent processing within the algorithm) would be optional but very interesting.
Thanking you for your time, I would very much appreciate your advice.

Comment: While it is not difficult to enumerate all possible paths recursively keep in mind, that in the worst case their number grows exponentially depending on the number of bridges. So it may not be a good idea to actually use such an algorithm unless one can guarantee that there are only well behaved graphs.

Comment: I'm okay with that if we follow my example, but in practice the input data won't allow that many paths. There will be a lot of different points for a few bridges. Could you share your ideas to list all the possible paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One could use a recursion like this (pseudo code):

```
findPath(from, to, path_to_from) {
  if from == to { output path_to_from }
  for all bridges going out from 'from' that were not already used in path_to_from {
    findPath(bridge.out, to, path_to_from + bridge)
  }
}
```

and call it with `findPath(A, B, empty_path)` to output all paths from A to B.